# Download a file with alert box using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm having a submit form where the form includes the following text fields

- First name
- Last name
- Email
- Password

When user enters the general password of "DEFAULTDOC" it will automatically download the file. But if not then it will show an alert box that says "Sorry your password is incorrect".

My codes is working fine. But the alert box in

*"You are now verified the file will automatically download."*

Doesn't show but the downloading of file is working also the inserting of data is working too. Except of showing the alert box. What could be the reason why the alert box doesn't show up?

here's my code: (dlform.php)

```
<?php
$database = 'db';
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$e = $_POST['e'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$f = $_POST['f'];
$l = $_POST['l'];

if($_POST['p'] == "DEFAULTDOC"){
    try
    {
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $query = "INSERT INTO dlform VALUES('','$p','$f','$l','$e')";
        $data = $connect->query($query);
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=InformationSheet.docm');
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('You are now verified the file will automatically download.');
            window.location.href='downloadform.php';
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    catch(PDOException $error)
    {
        $error->getMessage();
    }
}else{
?>
    <script>
        alert('Sorry your password is incorrect.');
        window.location.href='downloadform.php';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here's my html code:(downloadform.php)

```
<div class="container" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 600px;margin-top: 10%;">
    <center>
    <img src="images/menu_bar_logo.png" alt ="" style="width: 300px;"/></center>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <b>Note:</b>Fill up the following fields to get your form<br>
     <form method="post" action="dlform.php">
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">First name</span>
      <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="f" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Last name</span>
      <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="l" placeholder="Last name">
    </div>
    <Br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="e" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="p" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: is this your entire code or there's html in it?

Comment: This is the entire code of submit button from my downloadform.php

downloadform.php is just a html file with form action ="dlform.php" which is the code stated above

Comment: can u post the html code as well

Comment: i updated my post check it

Answer (score 2):

You try to use html tag while `dlform.php` only has php code. It won't work. Try to set the message into SESSION.

Your code

```
<script>
    alert('You are now verified the file will automatically download.');
    window.location.href='downloadform.php';
</script>
```

Change your code into php

```
$_SESSION['message'] = 'You are now verified the file will automatically download.';
header('Location: downloadform.php');
```

The same goes for incorrect password one.

And in your `downloadform.php`, add this code.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Message</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php unset($_SESSION['message']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code is in bootstrap style. This code is not an alert, but a modal similar to alert. It will show up if there is a message from `dlform.php`. After the message is shown, destroy the message session so it won't appear each time `downloadform.php` is reload, unless you submit the form.